# Python instaloader

Tags: python, instagram, instaloader

I saw on the Internet that many people encounter the error “JSON Query to graphql/query: HTTP error code 401.”, but I still haven’t found a solution.

In the code, using your login data, instaloader logs into your profile, but then throws an error.
[image]

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and a screenshot.